# How to put comma separator in input field of type number in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

this is my number input filed commponnet, and i want to make it on the UI as number with commas when use type for example: 100000 I want it show it like that => 100,000. im using react-bootstrap. someone can help me in how i can done it right?

this is an image on the its need to be on the UI

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfyls.png

```
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default function (props: any) {
    return (
        <Form.Control type="number" />
    )
}
```

Comment: Did either of 2 answers solved your problem or you're still looking for some better options?

Comment: still look for better answers

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
 const commaSeparators = num => {
      let numParts = num.toString().split('.');
      numParts[0] = numParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      return numParts.join('.');
    };
```

Edit: Short way:

```
const commaSeparators = num => num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Comment: You need to upload the code where you put the number @ODAppStudios

Comment: what do yo mean

Comment: its fetch that from this commponent with JSON form

Comment: I need to see your component with full template html and jsx